# Creating custom flashable partition on Android

Tags: android, android-source, firmware, android-firmware

I'm working on a project that utilizes Android to power the device.
In my case that's a tablet that uses standard MTK processor, and since the company that I work for produces a tablet by themselves, 
I have an access to a full firmware for it (device drivers, radio drivers, system, etc).
However, I am trying to create a custom partition that would store some data, but should be flashable via flash tool. After searching for the last two days, including https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions-images I only found that I can create the partition via adb. 
That's not what I want. I want to be able to create something like /MISC partiton that could be flashed via flash tool. 
Is it even possible to do something like this, and how?
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: `Flashed via ROM` what you referring ? while flashing ROM image, along with this you need to flash new partition ?

Comment: @Thiru Shetty exactly. I want to be able to have an .img file that can be added to a flash tool (like heimdall), and flash this partition along the boot, radio, recovery, etcetera

Comment: which flash you using eMMC ?

Comment: @ThiruShetty yes

Comment: Check the flash tool script, they will be doing `block partition` or `raw partition` of eMMC, update that script accordingly to add one more partition, then update the  flashing script to write your new image/data to new partition.

Comment: point me which tool or script you using to flash eMMC or how existing partitions created. will guide u.

Comment: It's the spflashtools=> https://spflashtools.com/category/linux

Comment: what is your memory or image map file, you provide while flashing ?

Comment: MTK uses so called scatter file. It describes the partitions, and block sizes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185121/discussion-between-thiru-shetty-and-mutantkeyboard).

Comment: Please elaborate on the partition you created via ADB... You may need to just edit the scatter file and partition information files on the device..   For example `proc/partinfo`